Is there any way to make this question (finishing school for wizards) on-topic?
What school of magic would the upper class want their children to learn quickly?
This question got upvoted to +5, but also closed for a number of reasons:

Too Story-Based
Not About Worldbuilding
What a character would do
Needs details and clarity

I don't think those close reasons are wrong--SE is just not suited for answering many types of worldbuilding questions. At the same time, I think the votes and comments generally show that people, even those who voted to close, think it's a good question and a fun thought.
(I also think that, though the question was closed, the outcome was pretty good overall. The question-asker was receptive to finding other communities/resources and people still get to read the question, even though it's closed. I'm not at all upset at how things went.)
If there was a way to make this question suited for the site, it would make an excellent addition to the site. For future questions in this vein, is there any way to refocus them in a way that makes them more answerable?
Related: Is it possible and reasonable to add "This is a high concept question" to the list of community-specific reasons to close a question? and the answers about how to make a 'what happens next' question on-topic.

Stack exchange (its owners, moderators and communities) have been teaching people that popularity does not absolve the poster from obedience to the rules for a very long time.

@JBH yeah, I tried to make it clear that I understand and approve of that! The question as it stands should have been closed, no doubt

The problem is that what you really want is Storybuilding.SE
I once tried to advocate for creating Storybuilding.SE. While the question retains a positive score, the answers strongly rejected the idea. Even Stack Exchange staff aren't fond of the idea. So, while we're the defacto storybuilding website, we're stuck with a set of rules that don't support storybuilding questions and a Help Center that explicitly states we don't help people write stories.
What makes this question a storybuilding question?
There is not and cannot be a single best answer.
Stack Exchange is intentionally designed to be a place where people can go to find specifically useful answers to problems more than just one person might have. It originated with Stack Overflow, a generic software Q&A site. Words like specific, objective, etc. make a lot of sense in the programming world, so it expanded into things like language and the hard sciences, which also enjoy that blessing.
Worldbuilding is and has always been a bit of an experiment. It's a miracle, really, that the site ever got out of Area 51, because worldbuilding is imaginative and creative. BUT, worldbuilding can be and should be specific and objective. After all, once a world rule is set the whole point is that the rule governs how stories are written.
And that's the problem.
You're asking how to write a story. It doesn't matter how you reword it because you're continuing to seek ideas (brainstorming or "fishing for ideas") about where your story should go. Any answer you receive is completely legitimate because you can write your story to embrace any answer you choose. (Compared to a worldbuilding rule where the story must be written to accommodate the rule or the world becomes inconsistent and difficult for readers to accept.)
But, because Worldbuilding.SE exists within the Stack Exchange universe, the Help Center forbids questions like that.

Questions that can't be asked without the circumstances of the story present are considered too story-based (because the circumstances change which answer is "best").

Questions that lead to all answers having equal value (there is no best answer because the question isn't about a world rule) are prohibited in the Help Center. Remember, Stack Exchange was developed with the intent of being specifically useful and the way it does that is through the objective selection of a single best answer.

The Help Center also forbids open-ended questions that seek what we call an infinite list of things. (Here, "infinite" means there's no reasonable limit to the expression of possible solutions of equal value.)


Unfortunately, we're stuck with SE's rules, so how could you make this question valid?
I'm belaboring a point, but simply put, you are required to ask a question that can have a single best answer.
Here's our problem, like most (if not all) storybuilding questions, you're brainstorming or intentionally looking for a large pool of answers so you can pick and choose an idea that suits your fancy. You may even award the coveted green checkmark to the answer you think is the coolest! But could you actually explain why that answer is better than every other answer in the context of the story-independent infrastructure of your world? This is why questions about character and organizational choices and motivations are off-topic, because you can't. The reason is as ethereal as the wind and as easily written into your story. Another reason could be used for a different civilization even though the question asked here would be fundamentally identical.
But let's set all that aside. Technically, there is a way your question can be made compliant with the rules: You can explain (clearly, precisely and objectively in the context of your world) how you will determine which answer will be the single best answer.
I've pointed this out to hundreds of querents over the years and I don't think a dozen took me up on it and explained what would make for a best answer and the majority produced points of judgement that were vacuous and meaningless (not creating a specific and objective framework for judgement because they didn't want a single best answer based on objective metrics. They really wanted a big pool of answers to give them ideas and were only looking for ways to keep their question from being closed before they got the list.
In short — they wanted to use Stack Exchange in a way it wasn't designed to be used.
So... you tell us. What list of "rules" (objective metrics in the context of your world) will you apply that we can use to guide us when answering your question such that you and anyone else can judge one answer better than another based on something other than, "that's a cool idea!"?
Now you know why we don't help people write stories. We actually love those kinds of questions — but they usually violate more than half of Stack Exchange's rules, which is why they get their own close reason.

As an aside that might not belong in my answer, the difference (in terms of your question) between storybuilding and worldbuilding is that you're not asking for help developing a culture (what is the nature of rich people?) you're asking for how they react given only a story-defined stimulus (what is their motivation?) The first is worldbuilding (the solution frames all future stories). The second is storybuilding (any answer can be written into the story).

Or better, Worldbuilding.Codidact, where good storybuilding questions would be valid!

No. Ultimately it's a question of plot. You can write plot questions detailed enough to have a single best answer but they can't be generalised, thus still falling short of "good question" and probably still getting "opinion based" VTCs. These questions also tend to contain so much detail that anyone who does answer fails to take most of the information into account. It's a pity because many of us love to talk plot but it absolutely doesn't work in this format.

There is (Almost) Always a Way

The Problem. --- I won't belabour the point that the question, as it is written, is essentially storybuilding rather than worldbuilding. Ash gave us the elevator pitch, JBH brought out the Tome of Explanation. I know you're not the querent, Kaia, but to succinctly hammer home the point: whenever we see "which of A, B, or C would people want", this always means that we're dealing with the wishes or desires of people. By definition this kind of question is and ought to be closed for being too story based.

As written, this question also dives straight into the heart of narrative necessity territory. In this case, the story needs for a particular school of magic to be chosen by the pregnant mom in order to exist as a story! Essentially, narrative necessity at its most fundamental means quite literally that any story (as story) needs certain things to happen, otherwise there is no story worth telling.

The problem of questions that focus on matters of plot, character choice or NN, such as this one, is simply that any school of magic will fit the bill and thus answer the question. This is obviously not a good fit for WB.SE!

BUT!

What's Actually Going on Here.  --- This is actually a great concept, and, as you say if we could hammer this question into shape it would indeed be a great addition to our repository! In its essence, what's going on here is a kind of Lamarckian inheritance. This exists in my own world, in  positive, negative, neutral, and medial aspects and could easily be applied to a child's later magical intuition whilst being fearfully and wonderfully knit in utero.

As a quick example (though would actually have answered another recent question): there is a curious branch of magic that concerns itself with the subtle magic of breast milk. Galactothaumery. Milkdwimmery. Whatever you want to call it, it is a well known fact of biology that little children, regardless of their race, require milk for sustenance. It's less well known that children fed the milk from a wetnurse of a race other than their own can receive certain benefits and / or malefits depending on the relative "cross pollination" if you will. Very much in the vein of the present question, choosy moms choose certain well vetted wetnurses from particular races and social & intellectual strata to supplement their little babies' diets. With very much the same desire in mind: to give their little ones every advantage they can afford.

How do we Fix This?  --- Our task then is how to look at hereditary thaumolamarckism from the external perspective rather than the internal. From the rules of the world perspective rather than the individual choice perspective. Let's look at the query!

So, the querent already deleted the paragraph that focused on a specific magical school. That's a good first step, because we really want to focus on the broader concept --- the rules of the world --- rather than the narrow choice that a family might make.

Good worldbuilding queries have five distinctive parts.
1. Marquee Question. The first thing we have to do to make this question properly answerable is to remodel the type of question! No character choice allowed! We need to focus on a world foundation rule, a law of nature, how such fundamentals might interact with magical systems, cultures, social strata, etc. The marquee question should grab our attention, point us in a particular direction, and make this querent's world and question stand out among the rest. I would look for something clever like Raising the Dead During Pregnancy: Your Child's Future is In Your Hands!
2. Background or Description.  I would argue that the querent's background piece is good as is. We just need to gain a good yet succinct understanding of the world we're working with. Here, we've got magic, science, technology, social structures, and educational systems in play. This means that the world itself is actually pretty well framed out. We should be able to help this querent with understanding how the laws of nature will get him where he wants to go.
3. Variables, Area of Focus.  We don't get much to go on here. The querent says "Note : This world isn't fully polished, so the full list of magic schools isn't set in stone. You can assume the usuals are there : Necromancy, Enchantments, Elements-bending, etc." The utility of necromancy is highly debatable; all three of these are fairly broad and could be interpreted in numerous different ways.
In this section, we respondents really need to be corralled and focused on certain things. We need to know a little more about these magic schools, a little more about how magic works, a little more about how culture and society interact with it. I mean, necroomancy could be the up and coming area of focus & study if this culture views dead bodies as a viable and legal resource to be put to work! Someone has to work the looms and the presses of this burgeoning industrial revolution! And slaves, children, and poor people all need to be fed, cared for and / or paid for their work; whilst zombie weavers really don't.
This section would need to be the querent's area of greatest focus.
4. Tell us the Real Question!  This is where the marquee question is properly developed. The querent should take the teaser question, align it with the information within the background and focus it through all the variables he wants us to focus on and then give us the big reveal. It doesn't have to be clever, but it should meet our expectations.
Obviously, it should not focus on the parents' choices, should not focus on entirely subjective requests like "what's the best" or "which would they want". It should focus on the rules of the world. Here we could be treated to a question of environmental concern: How might  a school of necromancy address a local community's environmental concerns over the increase in necromantically inclined student enrollment within the context of the city's several mechanised weaving factories?
5. Querent Expectations.  This section is often ignored, but a good querent will always lead us respondents where he wants to go. So, we need to be informed what he expects from a good answer: Special attention should be paid to bits falling off of the workers and the variety of putrid corpse liquors contaminating the cloth produced by a zombified necroworkforce; the acquisition of raw materials and the effects of exhumation on local water supplies; economic and social factors of loud and obnoxious corpse raising incantations coupled with the difficulty of herding hordes of newly exhumed liches, zombies, and feral skeletons.
